# There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' that has the key “Geslacht”

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

First of all, I'm a beginner in what concerns C#, Razor, ASP.NET... I want to make a 'DropDownListFor' for the genders with a 'List' but the problem is that I get the errormessage as described in the title. Here is my code:

Model

```
namespace Hoofdstuk5_MvcStudentForm1.Models.ViewModels
{
    public class StudentViewModel
    {
        public string Geslacht { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Controller

```
namespace Hoofdstuk5_MvcStudentForm1.Controllers
{
    public class StudentController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Student/Index
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        // GET: Student/Index
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(string groep)
        {
            ViewBag.Geslacht = new List<SelectListItem>
            {
                new SelectListItem { Text = "Female", Value = "1" },
                new SelectListItem { Text = "Male", Value = "2" }
            };
            return View(groep);
        }
    }
}
```

View

```
   @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Geslacht, ViewBag.Geslacht as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>, "--- Select ---", new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
   @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Geslacht, new List<SelectListItem> {
                                                               new SelectListItem { Text = "Male", Value = "1" },
                                                               new SelectListItem { Text = "Female", Value = "2" }
                                                               }, "--- Select ---", new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
   @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Geslacht, null, "--- Select ---", new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
```

The second 'DropDownListFor' works, but the first and third has to be from the controller, but it doesn't work and I don't know why? Can somebody help me please?

Comment: Probably because you only set `ViewBag.Geslacht` when you _post_ data.  You should probably add it when you _get_ data instead by putting it in the other `Index` method (the one without a parameter.

Comment: Thank you for your good answer :)

Comment: @KevinN what you are doing is very odd. I am not sure why you are doing this 3 times: `@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Geslacht`

Comment: @CodingYoshi It's an exercise that we have to do for school, how do to this in three different ways :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error means that the 2nd parameter of `DropDownListFor()` (`IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`) is `null` and therefore the method expects that the first parameter is `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` (which it's not)

In the first example, the value of `ViewBag.Geslacht` is `null` because you did not populate it in the GET method (although you do populate it in the POST method). Add `ViewBag.Geslacht = new List<SelectListItem>(...)` to the GET method.

In the 3rd example, you secifically set the 2nd parameter to `null`

Comment: I want to thank you for your answer. I put the ViewBag.Geslacht in the first Index which means there's nothing left in the second Index. When I open it, it works but when I want to save the form it gives me the same error as in the title.

Comment: You also need to repopulate the POST method (as per the code you currently have) if your return the view. Refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41784546/there-is-no-viewdata-item-of-type-ienumerableselectlistitem-that-has-the-key/41784613#41784613) for a more detailed explanation (and note that you typically only return the view is `ModelState` is invalid

Comment: Thank you, it works. Just asking, is there an easier way to do this without repopulating both actions but with the same idea?

Comment: To avoid repeating code, have a `private void ConfigureViewModel(StudentViewModel model)` method which sets the value of the `ViewBag` property (but your view model really should contain a property for `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` rather than using `ViewBag`). Then in the call that method in the GET method, and in the POST method is you return the view

Comment: for the detailed explanation (+1) from me.

Comment: Well if I have more experience with ASP.NET, Razor... I will look back to this answer if I have to do a similar form ;) Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You are sending a string to your view as the model:

```
return View(groep);
```

Therefore, you are getting that error. You have to pass a model to your view. Create a model like this:

```
// Give this a better name
public class SomeModel
{
    public List<SelectListItem> Geslacht { get; set; }
}
```

And then change your controller code to this:

```
// GET: Student/Index
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(string groep)
{
    var model = new SomeModel();
    model.Geslacht = new List<SelectListItem>
        {
            new SelectListItem { Text = "Female", Value = "1" },
            new SelectListItem { Text = "Male", Value = "2" }
        };
    return View(model);
}
```

If you need more things then just add more properties to your model.

Comment: That would make no sense for OP's 2nd example, and means hat you never get any valdation

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I honestly do not know why the OP is rendering the same dropdown for the same thing three times. But yes you are right.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you change a bit your model:

```
public class StudentViewModel
{
    public string Geslacht { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Geslachts { get; set; } 

    public StudentViewModel()
    {
        Geslachts = GetGeslachts();
    }

    public StudentViewModel(string geslacht)
    {
        Geslacht = geslacht;            
        Geslachts = GetGeslachts();
    }

    private IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetGeslachts()
    {
        return new List<SelectListItem> 
        {
            new SelectListItem 
            { 
                Text = "Select ---", 
                Value = string.Empty
            },
            new SelectListItem 
            { 
                Text = "Male", 
                Value = "1"
            },
            new SelectListItem 
            { 
                Text = "Female", 
                Value = "2"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then you could change your controller like below:

```
public class StudentController : Controller
{
    // GET: Student/Index
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(new StudentViewModel());
    }

    // GET: Student/Index
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(string groep)
    {
        return View(new studentViewModel(groep));
    }
}
```

Doing this changes entails that you should also change your View, to accept a StudentViewModel. Now at your view you could have the following:

```
@model oofdstuk5_MvcStudentForm1.Models.ViewModels.StudentViewModel 

@Html.DropDownListFor(model=>model.Geslacht, Model.Geslachts, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } )
```

Comment: The `Selected` property of `SelectListItem` is ignored when binding to a property so its pointless to set it.

Comment: Thanks, I will remove it.

Comment: Note you can also use `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Geslacht, Model.Geslachts, "Select ---", new { ... })` to add the `null` option

Comment: @StephenMuecke Thanks, I am aware of this and I prefer to declare it in the ViewModel. However, thank you for pointing this out :) !